# Is there an application to monitor bandwidth usage broken out to the application level for Linux (Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bandwidth, networking

I'm currently running Ubuntu on several machines and I need to track bandwidth usage per application. Is there a pre-built package or system that will track bandwidth usage and report on that usage broken out by application (or even just by port)?

Ideally I would like to be able to compare overall network utilization based on the running service and I've poked around a bit but haven't found anything that seems to be what I'm looking for. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**iftop** will display bandwidth usage by pairs of hosts, one of them being yours

**nethogs** will display bandwidth usage per process

**iptraf** will display bandwidth usage per connection

Comment: None of those applications do what I really want, which is watch the network for a period of time and then generate monthly reports. Those applications are all "real-timey". But, on the nethogs page there was a link (which was broken) to an application called "darkstat" that seemed like it was what I was looking for. So a quick Google later and I was on http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/darkstat.htm which had exactly what I needed. So, case closed. The answer is "darkstat". Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your fault for not stating explicitly "watch the network for a period of time" in your initial question :) If you are a hardcore SQL guy, you can install ulogd, set it up to log into a database (it supports many of them) and extract data for reports with SQL queries.

Comment: Had you stated in your original question your point regarding timescales, then someone would probably have mentioned mrtg (http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/) - note that on Linux / most POSIX systems you cannot reconcile traffic with applications - only with protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can reconcile traffic with applications.  You need to get at the socket details for a specified set of processes.  This requires that you get the data from inside the app/process and not from without.  Meaning that using OS I/Fs won't give you the details you are looking for.  Look at AppFirst, they do this.